# This extension may have been corrupted

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There are some topics on stackoverflow talk about this. I try to use update_url but still didn't work for me.

I test my extension on local (from folder), it work normally.

I upload to store with update_url inside manifest, it reaches above error "corrupted".

I use the pack function on Chrome to make crx file, and I use this file to install (offline install), it reaches same error "corrupted".
Here is my **manifest.json**

```
{
  "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
  "version": "2.3.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  ...
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: You might want to report it to [Chromium Issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list#), it might be because of Chrome version.

Comment: @HTCom I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, you just remove the tag updste_url